# Phonegap android application terminates after opening link in external browser

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem! I am developing a phonegap application for both iOS and Android. when i call

```
window.open(url, "_system")
```

on iOS it opens up but i can navigate to the place i was before in my app. but when i open a link in android and navigate back to the app it starts from the start. 
how can make the app stay the way it is when im leaving and return to it afterwards?

Comment: You might want to consider overriding the `onBackPressed` function, in order to set the page where you want the back button to leave you to.

Comment: I have a similar problem: when I open a new window using onclick="javascript:window.open("http:myurl","",""), the window opens and loads fine, but when I return to my app by pressing the back button, my entire app reloads. Do you also use jQueryMobile for the app by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Andorid

```
    function openInApp(link){
            console.log("Open Call"+ link);
            if(link.length<=1){

                    navigator.notification.alert(
                                        'Page not found..!',  // message
                                         null,         // callback
                                        'Title', // title
                                        'Ok'                   // buttonName
                                    );

            }else{
             var ref =      window.open(encodeURI(link), '_blank', 'location=yes');
              ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { 


                   navigator.notification.alert(
                                        'error: ' + event.message,  // message
                                         null,         // callback
                                        'Title', // title
                                        'Ok'                   // buttonName
                                    );

                });

            }
    }
```

IOS

```
    function openInApp(link){
            console.log("Open Call"+ link);
            if(link.length<=1){
                    navigator.notification.alert(
                                        'Page not found..!',  // message
                                         null,         // callback
                                        'Title', // title
                                        'Ok'                   // buttonName
                                    );
            }else{
              var ref = window.open(encodeURI(link), '_blank', 'location=no');
              ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { 


                   navigator.notification.alert(
                                        'error: ' + event.message,  // message
                                         null,         // callback
                                        'Title', // title
                                        'Ok'                   // buttonName
                                    );
                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: But i need to call _system not _blank because i want in a external browser not inappbrowser. is that possible for android?

Comment: means you do't need addressbar

Comment: Im not exatctly sure we understood each other. whats happening now: i press a url which is opened with window.open(url, "_system") and then for example dolphin or chrome is  opened depending on sustems default browser, then i hold the home button to switch between apps but when i click on my phonegap app im not returned to the last state but the app is lauched from the beggining but i would need to return to the state i was in. is this possible when opening url in the systems default browser?

Comment: which version you use now

Answer (score 0):

*Would have asked this in a comment, but one needs 50 reputation for that … :(*

In your `config.xml` do you have `exit-on-suspend` enabled? That is to say, do you have below `<preference>` element?

```xml
<cordova>
    ...
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
    ...
</cordova>
```